# How to use blur event for <img> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to close a `div` when I click anywhere on the screen except the image. The `onblur` function is not even calling the `alert`. Please help.

```js
$('.myClass').on('blur', function() {
  alert("test");
  $('.divClass').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="myImg.png" height="23" width="18" class="myClass" style="margin-top: -42px!important;margin-left: 145px !important;position:relative;" onclick="test()" />
```

Comment: FYI i dont think there is a `blur` event for image, `blur` are mostly used on inputs and text fields. Try `click` in place of `blur`, and there is no need for `onclick` attribute on image

Comment: Where you defined **.myClass** in your html ?

Comment: @RaeeshAlam right there in the img tag

Comment: You can achieve by button element so you need to wrap IMG inside button.

Answer (score 1):

`<img>` elements, by default, cannot be given the focus. If they can't be focused, then they can't *lose* focus and thus trigger a `blur` event. While you can use `tabindex` to change that, you then need to do a bunch of other work (e.g. add ARIA) to make it accessible. You are better off just using semantic HTML to start with.

1. Wrap the `<img>` with a `<button type="button">` element.
2. Move the event handlers from the `img` to the `button`
3. Apply CSS to remove as much of the default styling (like borders and the background colour) of the button as you like.

Answer (score 0):

By default `img` elements cannot have focus, therefore by proxy the cannot trigger a `blur` event. To work around this you can add a `tabindex` attribute to the `img` so that it can be selected. It will then trigger a `blur` event.

Note that this may interfere with the behaviour of screen readers and other accessibility tools, depending on the structure and content of your page, so use this technique carefully.

```js
$('.myClass').on('blur', function() {
  console.log("test");
  $('.divClass').hide();
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  margin-top: -42px!important;
  margin-left: 145px !important;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="myImg.png" height="23" width="18" class="myClass" tabindex="1" />

<div class="divClass">I will hide when the img loses focus...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `img` with `button` element. Then you can fire `blur` & `focus` event on button because of by-default `img` has not `blur` event.

```js
$('.myClass').on('blur', function(){
  $('.divClass').hide();
});
```

```css
.btn-forimg{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn-forimg myClass"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbpv.jpg" width="50"></button>
<div class="divClass">This div will disappear when button blur</div>
```